# MySQL query returns 0 rows when searching for value with dot (.) in string

Tags: mysql, select, row, setting

If I try to search for a value in mysql database and the string value contains dot in it, query returns 0 rows. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `username`='marco.polo'  --> 0 rows
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `username` LIKE '%.polo%'  --> 0 rows
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `username` LIKE 'polo'  --> Success
```

This appeared after moving server and database to another place. I know that dot is a set of extended regular expressions, but it should not apply to equal nor LIKE operator, simply because I don't use REGEXP in query.

I've tested the same query on my local database and it works fine.
Could there be a special setting in mysql that treats dot differently than it usually does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user1084605, I tried to replicate the problem (using MySQL version 5.1.37), but got exactly the opposite results as you. See below:

```
mysql> create table test (username varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into test values ('marco.polo');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE `username`='marco.polo';
+------------+
| username   |
+------------+
| marco.polo | 
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE `username` LIKE '%.polo%';
+------------+
| username   |
+------------+
| marco.polo | 
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE `username` LIKE 'polo';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

According to the MySQL docs, the only special characters when using the LIKE operator are "%" (percent: matches 0, 1, or many characters) and "_" (underscore: matches one and only one character).
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

A "." (period) does have special meaning for MySQL's REGEXP operator, but it should still match a literal period in your column.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html

Can you replicate the SQL statements I ran above and paste your results in reply?

Comment: After hours of debugging I found out that default character set of the table was armenian (the creator probably did not pay attention when creating the database, therefore first on the list was selected). After running a few ALTER statements and changing to utf8 everything started to work.

Thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

As *@[cen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084605/cen)* already mentioned, character set can causes that problem.
I have had this sample:

```
`email` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET 'armscii8' NOT NULL,
```

this is was in the .sql dump, which I receive.

So, when I was trying to fetch object with this email 
I couldn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

The below query takes care of the scenario when we have only **DOT** operator in the columns.

```
 SELECT * FROM test WHERE `username` LIKE '%.%';
```