# How to Query in PHP/ MySQL when there is a period (.) in String

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How do I query from a MySQL database when I have a period (.) in string using PHP.

```
$variable = "my.email@email.com";
$variable = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $variable);
$query = "Select * from table WHERE email = '$variable' ";
```

Apparently this works when I ran it in PhpMyAdmin SQl tab. But when I run it In my code it does not work. Other strings that don't have a period using the same code are working perfectly. What could be the issue

for those who are asking for my original code here it is

```
//I get the emails from the url  

    $notit = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['username']);

//I pass my variable in the query

    $sql = "SELECT * ";
    $sql.=" FROM ordrs ";
    $sql.=" WHERE client_email = '$notit' ";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("try again");
```

Comment: this isn't the actual code you are using is it

Comment: Try this mysql_real_escape_string($variable).

Comment: have a look in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408905/mysql-query-returns-0-rows-when-searching-for-value-with-dot-in-string

Comment: Are you using core PHP code or any framework ?

Comment: And where's `execute` or `query` or what do you use to run your `$query`?

Comment: @e4c5 I have updated that's exacly how it is.

Comment: if not working maybe alter the database into utf-8 and check if it works.

Comment: @claudios I tried still doesn't work

Comment: I wonder why noone asked yet what "doesn't work" does mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured where the issue was the query was fine the error was coming from json_encode which I din't expect . I hope this question helps others in the future who are facing the problem questioned. Thanks for the help

thanks for the help. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Try this code it works for me try using PDO.

```
 try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}", $db_username, $db_password);
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

        }

        catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

  $email = "code.sample@mail.co.ke";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = ?');
  $stmt->bindParam(1, $email);
  $stmt->execute();
  $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Sample output by eg: `echo '<h2>'. $user['email'] . '</h2>';`

Answer (score 1):

You should use prepared statements. Otherwise, possible of sql injection vulnerability. 
Example:

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("Select * from table WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

// set parameters and execute
$email = "john.doe@example.com";
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: A very succinct example to why manual escaping is a waste of time because prepared statements are almost always less code and way more secure. You can actually bind directly vs `$_GET` to save the step of assigning to `$email`.